# How to send js vars to plugin controller using ajax?

Tags: octobercms

Im trying to create a very simple plugin that tracks site visits. I need to get the page referrer using JS document.referrer, pass it to a variable, and send that variable to the plugin controller or to the component, so I can store it in the database. I've been struggling with this for days...Tried everything I found on Google...Nothing works. Please, help

The script using vanilla JS and PHP is really easy to implement. The problem is to integrate it in OctoberCMS :(

```
// js
(function(){

function makeXHRRequest( url, callback, method, dataType ) {
  if(!window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
    return null;
  }
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  method = method || 'GET';
  dataType = dataType || 'text/plain';
  req.open( method, url );
  req.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', dataType);

  req.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( req.readyState === 4 ) { 
      if( req.status === 200 ) {
        callback.success(req);
      }
      else {
         callback.failure(req);
      }
    }
  }
  req.send(); 
  return req; 
}

// current page url
function getCurrentPage(){
    var urlPath = window.location.pathname;
    var domain  = window.location.hostname;
    var hostName;
    if (urlPath === '/'){
        hostName = urlPath.replace(urlPath, domain);
        return hostName;
    }
    else {
       return urlPath;
    }
}

// page referrer
function getPageReferrer(){
  return document.referrer;
}

function RequestPageInfo() {
  var pageReferrer = getPageReferrer();
  var currentPage  = getCurrentPage();

  var queryVars = 'current_page='+currentPage+'&page_referrer='+pageReferrer;

  var callback = {
      success: function(req) {
       document.getElementById('page-result').innerHTML = req.responseText;
      },
      failure: function(req) {
       document.getElementById('page-result').innerHTML = 'An error has occurred.';
      }
  }

  // request data
  makeXHRRequest('tvisitor.php?'+queryVars, callback, 'POST', 'application/json' );
}

window.onload = function() {
  RequestPageInfo();
};

})();

// visitor.php
// get ajax requested page url vars
$referrerPage = isset($_GET['page_referrer']) ? $_GET['page_referrer'] : "";
$PageUrl  = isset($_GET['current_page']) ?  $_GET['current_page'] : "";
```

Answer (score 2):

## Disclaimer :)

For what you want to have, you actually don't need AJAX or any javascript at all. The current page url and referer info can all be accessed in the server side php code (OctoberCMS has also handy [helper functions](https://octobercms.com/docs/services/helpers#method-request) for that). And the database storing is also obviously handled there.

But as the main question is actually how to send variables from the frontend js to the server-side via the to be processed there, through the [AJAX framework](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/ajax) here is an explanation on this.

---

## Basic AJAX usge in October

The most basic ingredient you will need is an [AJAX handler](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/ajax#ajax-handlers). You define AJAX handlers in the code section of whatever appropriate template you have at hand: page, partial (also component partials), layout.

October templates of all these kinds are seperated into up to three sections:

```
# config section
# page variables and stuff can be set up here
title = "Hello"
==
<?php // code section
function thisAndThat()
{
    return "whatever";
}
?>
==
{# twig markup section #}
<h1>{{this.page.title}}</h1>
<p>You can use twig here.</p>
```

AJAX handlers should follow the naming convention `onThisAndThat`. Otherwise, they can't be called through the framework.

Parameters are sent through the POST method. So you would use them in your handler like so:

```
function onTrackVisit()
{
    $referer=post('referer'); // assuming the 'referer' and 'page' variables have been sent as POST parameters
    $page=post('page');       // post(' ... ') is just a helper function for $_POST[' ... ']
    doStuffWith($page, $referer); // to store them in the database ...
}
```

---

### How to call an AJAX handler with parameters from JavaScript

Okay, so now how is the AJAX handler called?

**TLDR version:** (for further details I recommend to [RTFM :)](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/ajax#ajax-handlers))

You can just do

```
$.request("onTrackVisit", {data: {page: getCurrentPage(), referrer: getPageReferrer()}});
```

in a javascript included in your template's markup section with the functions you had already defined in your example. Now these variables are sent as POST parameters through the AJAX request to your `onTrackVisit()` handler on the server side.

(A common cleanly way to put your javascript is to put it in between

```
{%put scripts%}
<script> ... </script>
{%endput%}
```

so that it will be appended at the `{% scripts %}` placeholder in your layout, if that exists; or, if you are building a plugin component, you can add a line

```
$this->addJs("path/to/your/script.js"); //(relative to the plugin root dir.)
```

in the `onRun()` method of your component class (in `{{your_plugin}}/components/VisitTracker.php` or whatever it is).)

---

## Buildig the plugin and a component to handle the database stuff.

So now, for handling the plugin and component scaffolding and handling the database stuff, my below previous answer may still be useful. Probably has too many details. But I think you can live with it. :-P

The only thing you would need to change to do it the way you wanted, by sending the page and referer through AJAX, would be to rename the `onRun` method below to `onTrackVisit` or something, replace

```
    $thisVisit.page = request()->url();
    $thisVisit.referer = request()->header('referer');
```

with

```
    $thisVisit.page = post('page');
    $thisVisit.referer = post('referer');
```

and put some code in your component's default template to make an `onTrackVisit` AJAX call with the required `page` and `refer(r)er` data parameters from your javascript.

---

This answer explains how to create a plugin with a component for logging page visits with the data "page" (url) and "referer" that are to be stored in a corresponding dedicated database table.

Though obviously you already have some plugin created that you're fiddling with, I'll start from the beginning so every step is logical and easily understood. I apologize for perhaps exaggeratedly thorough details and longwinded explanations for some context here or there.

First of all create a basic plugin (scaffolding) with some sensible name:

```
php artisan create:plugin YourNameSpace.VisitTracker
```

This will just create the directory `plugins/yournamespace/visittracker` and the files `plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/Plugin.php` (the main plugin file; code for registering all your plugin's components, extensions etc. goes in here) and `plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/updates/version.yaml` (version information file; database migration info goes in here).

Since you want to store data for visits in the database, you'll need a database model (with a corresponding database table) for that.

I assume you simply want a table of singular records called "visits".

```
php artisan create:model YourNameSpace.VisitTracker Visit
```

This command creates a new basic model class named "Visit" without any interesting properties, and a migration file for creating a corresponding database table.

The Visit model class is now being defined in `plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/models/Visit.php` and the migration file in `plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/updates/create_visits_table.php`

You don't need to change anything in the model class definition file. The model will just make use of the database table with the corresponding name that is created by the migration file. The migration file needs to be run at some point in order to actually create the database table. In order for this to happen orderly you have to change the `plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/updates/version.yaml` to include the migration file in your newest version, like so:

**plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/updates/version.yaml**

```
1.0.1:
- First version of VisitTracker
- create_visits_table.php
```

This tells october that with installing version 1.0.1 (the very first version in this case) the migration file `create_visits_table.php` should be run to update the database.

But first you still have to tweak it a little bit to make it suit your needs.

Modify the `up()` function in your migration file like so (added code between `BEGIN INSERT` and `END INSERT`; comments just explain a little bit) -

in **plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/updates/create_visits_table.php**:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('yournamespace_visittracker_visits', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
        $table->increments('id'); 

        /*
         * BEGIN INSERT
         *
         * your actual data columns
         */

        // include columns for page and refer(r)er:
        $table->string('page');

        // see http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/42630/referer-or-referrer/42636        
        $table->string('referer')

        /*
         * END INSERT
         */

        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

You can now tell october to (re-)create all the plugin's database tables by running all its migration files from scratch with the command:

```
php artisan plugin:refresh YourNamespace.VisitTracker
```

Okay, now to the frontend.

You need to create component to put your code into for doing the tracking. Again, there is an artisan command to create the scaffolding for that. Let's call the component "VisitTracker", just like the plugin itself here:

```
php artisan create:component YourNamespace.VisitTracker VisitTracker
```

This creates basic scaffolding for the component named "VisitTracker".

Since your component should not do anything visibly, you should probably make the default template `plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/components/visittracker/default.htm` empty, and all the action would take place in the component's onRun() function, which you define as follows, after making sure to include

in **plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/components/VisitTracker.php**:

```
use TestCase\VisitTracker\Models\Visit as VisitModel;
```

at the beginning of the file

in **plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/components/VisitTracker.php**:

```
public function onRun()
{
    $thisVisit = new VisitModel();
    $thisVisit.page = request()->url();
    $thisVisit.referer = request()->header('referer');
    $thisVisit->save();
}
```

Finally, you still need include your component in the Plugin.php file's `registerComponents()` function, so that it is usable in CMS pages. In `plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/Plugin.php` inside the Plugin class (the function is already there, you just need to fill it properly)

in **plugins/yournamespace/visittracker/Plugin.php**:

```
public function registerComponents()
{
    return [
        'YourNamespace\VisitTracker\Components\VisitTracker' => 'VisitTracker',
    ];
}
```

Hope this will help you in some way. Follow-up questions in comments for clean-up or clarification are very welcome.

<sub>(If you'd like to have a dedicated stackechange community for OctoberCMS, plese support the [octobercms.stackexchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/97119/octobercms). I'll remove this annoing message, once that goal is achieved - promise :) )</sub>

Comment: “For what you want to have, you actually don't need any frontend javascript at all. The current page url and referer info can all be accessed in the server side php code (OctoberCMS has also handy helper functions for that…”

1) **page referrer** var is just one **example** of all the variables and values one could need to generate in JavaScript.

Comment: 2) There can be many reasons to choose JS over PHP to generate a result. In this case, for example,** php http referrer** result would look something like this:

http://www.google.co.nz/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=3&sqi=2&ved=0CCkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.electrictoolbox.com%2Fusing-settimeout-javascript%2F&rct=j&q=javascript%20settimeout&ei=IijsTIzYAYLCcfeB2fYO&usg=AFQjCNFJ5Fn8pm2lVcZCt46Jn6A7v_S4TQ
domcument.referrer would be: www.google.com, which seems to me easier to store in the db.

Comment: “Your question's title does not even actually make total sense after all. It seems you are confused about the concept of a plugin controller, and it is not clear how one would "send js variables" to it.)”

Sorry if my question does not make sense to you. I come from Laravel, and I’m learning Oct. I have a decent grasp of plugin building, but I’m having a really hard time wrapping my head around the Ajax Framework. I find it inflexible and difficult to implement. So maybe you could modify your answer, and make it more related Ajax Framework and Ajax implementation in general in OctoberCMS :)

Comment: So I still have the same question: **How can I send JS variables to the server via ajax request in OctoberCMS?**

Do you know any other directory other than controller and component where it would make more sense to send JS variables using ajax? How or where do I get the variables values in the server so I can them in the database? Where can I place jscript.js and processajax.php?

Comment: Okay, I hear ya. And I almost expected this. :)
Sorry also for getting back late.

I have amended my answer now to get at the AJAX stuff.

**TLDR:** ```$.request("onTrackVisit", {data: {page: getCurrentPage(), referrer: getPageReferrer()}});``` will call the Ajax handler onTrackVisit() on the server side, which you have to define in the code section of your template.

Comment: I had wanted to add the explanation long ago, but did not know where to start, without getting long-winded :) and then I was busy.

Also, your idea of sending js variables to the component of course makes sense. I had somehow overlooked that and only seen "sending to the controller", but how would you do that from the frontend? Controllers are in the backend. And of course there's also AJAX handling there, but, that's separate... yeh, you see, hard to gauge the level of understanding of the concepts involved here. And then difficult to see from where to start. Sorry for that.

Comment: But I enjoy being longwinded :)